# RetrofitError.getKind Example

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to catch error from RetrofitError. Below is the code what I use.

```
if (exception instanceof RetrofitError) {
    RetrofitError retrofitError = (RetrofitError) exception;
    m_tvStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String msg = "";
    if (retrofitError.getResponse() != null) {
        if (retrofitError.getResponse().getStatus() > 500) {
                msg = "Network error HTTP ("
                        + retrofitError.getResponse().getStatus() + ")";
                if (retrofitError.getMessage() != null
                        && !retrofitError.getMessage().isEmpty()) {
                        msg += ": " + retrofitError.getMessage();
                }
            }else if (retrofitError.getBody() == null) {
                msg = exception.getMessage();
            } else if (retrofitError.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
                msg = getString(R.string.connection_error);

            } else if (retrofitError.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                msg = getString(R.string.connection_timeout);
            }
        }else if (retrofitError.getKind() !=null){
            if (retrofitError.getKind().name().equalsIgnoreCase("NETWORK"))
                msg = getString(R.string.connection_timeout);
            else
                msg = getString(R.string.connection_error);
        }
        m_tvStatus.setText(msg);
   }
}
```

The question is how to capture message from RetrofitError.getKind(). In my code above i use hard code equalsIgnoreCase("NETWORK") to decide what kind of error.

Is there any better way to capture error message from RetrofitError.getKind() ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, `getKind()` will never be `null`. It's also an enum so stop doing string comparison on it!

The appropriate way to handle this is to `switch` on `getKind()` and act appropriately.

```
switch (error.getKind()) {
  case HTTP:
    // TODO get message from getResponse()'s body or HTTP status
    break;

  case NETWORK:
    // TODO get message from getCause()'s message or just declare "network problem"
    break;

  case CONVERSION:
  case UNEXPECTED:
    throw error;

  default:
    throw new AssertionError("Unknown error kind: " + error.getKind());
}
```

Comment: Sorry the first paragraph is meant to sound encouraging because it saves you from a bunch of work. But re-reading it I sound kind of rude!

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a Java Enum value, just use

`retrofitError.getKind().toString()` to get a string representation of this error enum.

or

`retrofitError.getKind().name()` to [get its declaration name (eg: `NETWORK`. `UNEXPECTED` etc)](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RetrofitError.Kind.html)